# Как будет выглядеть Mat после Mat = Mat*Mat > 0 в OpenCV?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

У меня есть кусок кода, который нужно переписать на с#, но мне не понятна вот эта конструкция

```
Mat mask1 = Q.row(2).mul(Q.row(3)) > 0;
```

В коде ниже

```
std::vector<Mat> allTriangulations(4);
Mat Q;

triangulatePoints(P0, P1, points1, points2, Q);
if(triangulatedPoints.needed())
    Q.copyTo(allTriangulations[0]);
Mat mask1 = Q.row(2).mul(Q.row(3)) > 0;
Q.row(0) /= Q.row(3);
Q.row(1) /= Q.row(3);
Q.row(2) /= Q.row(3);
Q.row(3) /= Q.row(3);
mask1 = (Q.row(2) < distanceThresh) & mask1;
Q = P1 * Q;
mask1 = (Q.row(2) > 0) & mask1;
mask1 = (Q.row(2) < distanceThresh) & mask1;
```

Как будет выглядеть `mask1` если выражение возвращает только 1 или 0?

Comment: Посмотрите на устройство класса `Mat`, вся суть ваших непоняток там.

Comment: @Bulson видимо там получается просто строка из нулей и единиц. Смысл маски пока все равно непонятен в документации пишут 
`mask – Input/output mask for inliers in points1 and points2. If it is not empty, then it marks inliers in points1 and points2 for then given essential matrix E. Only these inliers will be used to recover pose. In the output mask only inliers which pass the cheirality check.`